# how to display images in UIwebview when they get loaded from net in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uiimage

My content of uiwebview contains images and text. I have the text but the images get loaded from net. If there is no net then symbol of no image comes (the default as it looks in browser). I have seen an application where it left no blank space for images if there is no net. If net is present then the images are inserted between the text.

How can I achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an `onerror`attribute to your images:

```
<img src="yourimage.png" onerror="this.width=0" />
```

If the UIWebView cannot load the image (e.g. because there is no internet connection) an error event is dispatched and the javascript inside your `onerror` attribute gets called. If you set the image's width to 0, the broken image icon is not displayed.